# Name sorting using counting sort

Tags: string, sorting, counting-sort

I'm having trouble sorting names in alphabetical order using counting sort, for instance I'm suppose to sort in alphabetical order and have number input added to it for example `0001 Alex Smith, Gregory John, Alex Smith, Adam Richard, Alex Ryan`. The output should be in this order:

Adam Richard
Alex Ryan
Alex Smith
Gregory John

My code so far:

```
public class Names 
{
    //private static int[] c;

 public ArrayList<String> getUserInput()
{
        ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>(); 
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (in.hasNext()) 
     {
         names.add(in.next());  
        System.out.println(names); 
     }
      in.close();
    return names;
}
 private static CountingSort(int A[], int B[], int k[])
{
    int i;
    int C[0];
    for(i = 0; i <= k; i++){
        C[i]=0;
    }

    for(int j=1; j <= A.length; ){
        C[A[j]] = C[A[j]] + 1;
    }//C[i] now contains numbers of elements equals to i
    for(int i=1; i < k; i++){
        C[i] = C[i] + C[i - 1];

    }
    for(int j = A.length; j--){
    B[C[A[j]]] = A[j];
    C[A[j]] = C[A[j]] - 1;   
   }
}
}
```

Comment: [Counting sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort) is only useful for small input ranges (e.g. small integers). Did you mean radix sort?

Comment: crossposted http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/java/threads/384308

Answer (score 3):

**Preparing Data**

a. Make lengths of each string equal. Add ‘*’ at the end of each string to make all lengths equal.

```
Modified Data — [‘a*’, ‘bd’, ‘cd’, ‘ab’, ‘bb’, ‘a*’, ‘cb’]
```

b. Convert this modified data strings into numbers by assigning positional values to letters. a-z to 1–26 and * to 0. So this becomes 2-dimensional array.

```
Converted Data — [[1,0],[2,4],[3,4],[1,2],[2,2],[1,0],[3,2]]
```

**Counting Sort**

1. Create Count Array of n-dimensions
   where n=length of longest string (in this case 2) and,
   number of columns in each dimension = maximum value in ‘Converted Data’ (in this case 4) +1(added for ‘*’).
   So, a count array of 5x5 is created.

For example — if the longest length of string was 5 and highest character ‘f’ then an array of 7x7x7x7x7 would be created.

And just like normal count array, store values based on ‘Converted Data’. For example, for [1,0] the value stored is 2.
Count Array

2. Cumulate this n-dimensional array starting from [0,0] all the way to [4,4].
3. Now similarly use the ‘Converted Data’ with Count Array to determine the position of each string in sorted array. For ex. — [1,0] (a*) the position is 2.
   And similarly after determining position, subtract 1 from that value in count array. So value at [1,0] in Count array becomes 1. Similarly position of [2,4] (bd) is 5 in sorted array.

https://playcode.io/475393

Answer (score 0):

Counting sort is the wrong sorting algorithm for this problem. The counting sort algorithm is designed to sort integer values that are in a fixed range, so it can't be applied to sort strings.

On the other hand, you *could* use radix sort for this problem. Radix sort works by sorting the input one digit or character at a time, and it's very well-suited for sorting strings. There are two general flavors of radix sort - most-significant-digit radix sort and least-significant-digit radix sort. The MSD flavor of radix sort isn't too reminiscent of counting sort, but LSD radix sort works by using counting sort one character at a time. If you really must use counting sort, I'd recommend investigating LSD radix sort as an option.